# Finding number $\overline{ATOM}$ such that $\sqrt{\overline{ATOM}}=A+\overline{TO}+M$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\overline{ATOM}$ is four digits number such that
$\sqrt{\overline{ATOM}}=A+\overline{TO}+M$. How to find the numbers  ?
I am sure that $M\neq2,3,7,8$ because it is a perfect square.

I wrote $\overline{ATOM}=M+10O+100T+1000T$ and r.h.s as $M+O+10T+A$ I tried some algebraic calculations, but I  can't go further more. I have no clue to solve this problem. 
If you can give an idea to solve, I am thankful.

Comment: whta means overline here ?

Comment: @Adam That you consider the letters as a single number. For example, $\overline{TO}$ indicates a two-digits number and $T$ and $O$ are its digits.

Comment: Answer: 1296 and 6724 by computer brute-force. However that doesn't help in finding a solution.

Comment: @user202729:Thank you ,I solved it by Matlab programming .BUt know I am looking for a mathematical idea!

Comment: @user202729 Not the only solution. $6724$ is also a solution.

Comment: You can rule out $M$ being zero as well. For then $O$ would also be zero (because the number is divisible by 10 but also a perfect square); hence the square root ends in zero; hence, by the equation, $A$ is zero.

Comment: $ATOM$ will have residue $0$ or $1$ mod $9$.  Else casting out nines fails.

Comment: @rubik Can you giver a reference for it? I woul like to ad it to wikipedia. TIA

Comment: @Adam I'm afraid I don't remember any authoritative sources for this notation. However, every question on this site in this topic employs it, so it must come somewhere. I suggest you ask a question here, you'll get many useful inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=\overline{A}+\overline{TO}+\overline{M}, n^2=\overline{ATOM}$.  Clearly these must have the same digital root so $n^2\equiv n \bmod 9$.  Since $9$ has only one distinct prime factor $n\equiv 0$ or $n\equiv 1 \bmod 9$.

The tens digit of $n$ must be greater than $2$ for $n^2$ to have four digits without an initial zero. We cannot have $n$ ending with $0$, else $\overline{OM}=00$ forcing $A=0$. 
Nor does $n$ end with $5$ since that leads to $\overline{OM}=25$ and $A=8$, but there are no squares having the form $8T25$.

So we try $n=36, 54, 63, 72, 81, 99$ among multiples of $9$; and $n=37, 46, 64, 73, 82, 91$ among numbers one greater than a multiple of $9$.  $n=36$ and $n=82$ work.

Comment: Good answer....

Answer (score 2):

Not a very efficient solution: Let $x=\overline{TO}$. Then $$1000A+10x+M=x^2+2x(A+M)+(A+M)^2$$ and $$x^2+(2A+2M-10)x+(A+M)^2-(1000A+M)=0$$Discriminant must be a perfect square, that is $$\Delta_x^{'}=9(110A-M)+25=k^2$$ Thus $k=9l+4$ or $k=9l+5$.

They lead to $110A-M+1=9l(9l+8)$ and $110A-M=9l(9l+10)$, respectively. Consider modulo $9$ and find possible values of $A$ from possible values of $M$ as you and @symplectomorphic ruled out them. Then find $x$. You have 10 cases to check.